# How to multiply matricies with algebra in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have two numpy matrix objects in my code, one is a matrix of numbers and the other is a matrix of variables that I do not want to assign values to. The result I want is this:

```
[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]

multiplied by the column vector

[['i8'],
 ['i4'],
 ['i9'],
 ['i5'],
 ['i2'],
 ['i1'],
 ['i7'],
 ['i6'],
 ['i3']]

Gives:
[[         i8+i1],
 [i4+i1-i7+i6-i3],
 [         i9+i1],
 [      i5+i6-i3],
 [      i2-i1+i3]]
```

I have looked at the numpy linear algebra section and am unable to find anything that works. I've tried using np.dot(), np.multiply(), tried converting them to arrays and I keep getting signature matching type error (which I assume is because the second matrix is made of strings). How can I multiply these to get my equations?

- I know using numpy matrix objects are not advised, the reason they are implemented here is because a python package that I'm using to obtain these matricies is returning them that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "I know using numpy matrix objects are not advised"? Is it generally not recommended, or in some contexts like yours?

Comment: _variablers that I do not want to assign values to_ -- numpy doesn't do that.

Comment: @j1-lee Numpy matrix objects are not reccomended in general, the only reason they still exist is to interact with scipy stuff, the general intention is to remove the numpy.matrix class eventually. more information is on the numpy docs

Comment: The use of `np.matrix` is irrelevant.  The issue here is multiplication of numbers and strings.  `1.0*'l1'`

Comment: @CharlesKelly Oh I see, I didn't even know `np.matrix` exists. I thought you meant `np.array`. Thank you for clarifying it. I've learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With object dtype arrays, functions like `np.dot` try to delegate the action to the multiply and add methods of the elements.

Thus I define a class:

```
In [467]: class Y:
     ...:     def __init__(self,astr):
     ...:         self.value = astr
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return self.value
     ...:     def __mul__(self, other):
     ...:         if other==0:
     ...:             return Y('')
     ...:         elif other==1:
     ...:             return self
     ...:         elif other==-1:
     ...:             return Y('-'+self.value)
     ...:         else:
     ...:             return Y(str(other)+self.value)
     ...:     def __add__(self, other):
     ...:         if self.value=='':
     ...:             return other
     ...:         elif other.value=='':
     ...:             return self
     ...:         else:
     ...:             return Y(self.value+'+'+other.value)
     ...:
```

and make an array of the objects:

```
In [468]: y = np.array([Y('i1'),Y('i8'),Y('j3')])
In [469]: y
Out[469]: array([i1, i8, j3], dtype=object)
```

with that `dot` looks reasonable.

```
In [470]: np.dot(y,[-1,0,1])
Out[470]: -i1+j3
In [471]: type(_)
Out[471]: __main__.Y
```

`Y` may need some tweaking, but that gives the basic idea.

But beware that all this multiplication and adding is taking place in Python.  None of this is compiled, so there's nothing special about its speed.

---

ANd with your arrays, tweaked a bit:

```
In [474]: In [437]: x = np.array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     ...:      ...:  [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.],
     ...:      ...:  [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
     ...:      ...:  [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.],
     ...:      ...:  [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]], dtype=int)
     ...:      ...:
     ...:      ...: #multiplied by the column vector
     ...:      ...:
     ...:      ...: y = np.array([['i8'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i4'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i9'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i5'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i2'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i1'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i7'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i6'],
     ...:      ...:  ['i3']])
     ...: 
In [475]: x
Out[475]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  1]])
In [476]: y
Out[476]: 
array([['i8'],
       ['i4'],
       ['i9'],
       ['i5'],
       ['i2'],
       ['i1'],
       ['i7'],
       ['i6'],
       ['i3']], dtype='<U2')
In [477]: y = np.frompyfunc(Y,1,1)(y)
In [478]: y
Out[478]: 
array([[i8],
       [i4],
       [i9],
       [i5],
       [i2],
       [i1],
       [i7],
       [i6],
       [i3]], dtype=object)
```

and the dot:

```
In [479]: np.dot(y.T,x.T)
Out[479]: 
array([[i8+i1, i4+i1+-i7+i6+-i3, i9+i1, i5+i6+-i3, i2+-i1+i3]],
      dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct: matrix multiplication is not defined on non-numeric types.  We do have simple integer replication of strings: 'i5' * 2 yields 'i5i5', which is not what you need.  Also note that you're using float coefficients, so even *that* interpretation is invalid.

You seem to be working with symbolic linear algebra.  NumPy does not have built-in operations for this domain.  Depending on your application, you may be able to use `sympy`.  If not, I expect that what you need is to define your own class.

Comment: Making my own class was my initial intention, but I assumed there would be a function for this that would be much more efficient than just using basic loops and comparisions to build my output matrix. I'll have a look at sympy, thanks